# Share url in Flutter using share_plus doesn't show Safari in picker list

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, share-plus

When sharing a URL, I need to list Safari in the picker dialog in iOS. I'm using [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) version 6.2.0

Code: `Share.share('https://www.google.com')`

Actual result:

[image]

Expected result(similar to News app on iOS):

[image]

I don't insist on this library. Any solution is appreciated.